# how to set viewpager image as wallpaper

Tags: java, android, position, android-viewpager, android-wallpaper

I am swiping gridview images in viewpager and I want to set viewpager current showing images as wallpaper.
I tried this: but got error "unfortunately stopped"

```
// set wallpaper on button click
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wll);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v2) {
                // // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                        .getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.id.view_pager);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

full code:

SwipeActivity.java

```
package com.td.gridview;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SwipeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.swipe_view);

        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        final int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position); 

        // send image to full_view.xml screen on button click
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xoom);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // get intent data
                Intent i3 = getIntent();

                // Selected image id
                int position = i3.getExtras().getInt("id");
                // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                Intent i2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Full_Zoom.class);
                // passing array index
                i2.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i2);
            }
        });
        //

        // set wallpaper on button click
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wll);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v2) {
                // // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                        .getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.id.view_pager);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        int[] icons = MainActivity.ICONS;

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return icons.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Context context = SwipeActivity.this;
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            // int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
            // R.dimen.padding_large);
            // imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            imageView.setImageResource(icons[position]);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm failed to find any way to set viewpager image as wallpaper so please help me here.

Answers will be help full so try to give answer not just pass me to other links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**i got my answer**

```
package com.td.gridview;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SwipeActivity extends Activity {

    protected int curruntPosition;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.swipe_view);

        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        final int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Here you can set the wallpaper
                curruntPosition = arg0;

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

        // set wallpaper on button click
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wll);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v2) {
                // // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //

                //

                WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                        .getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    myWallpaperManager
                            .setResource(MainActivity.ICONS[curruntPosition]);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    //

    //

    public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        int[] icons = MainActivity.ICONS;

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return icons.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Context context = SwipeActivity.this;
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            // int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
            // R.dimen.padding_large);
            // imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            imageView.setImageResource(icons[position]);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the position of the current selected page/image. you can get it by making a custom `OnPageChangeListener` like this:

```
public class MyOnPageChangeListener extends OnPageChangeListener {

    private int currentPosition = 0;

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        currentPosition = position;
    }

    public final int getCurrentPosition () {
        return currentPosition ;
    }
}
```

Copy this class into your `SwipeActivity`. Then create a `MyOnPageChangeListener` object and set it on the viewPager:

```
...
// create MyOnPageChangeListener
final MyOnPageChangeListener mListener = new MyOnPageChangeListener();
...
// set MyOnPageListener on the viewPager
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mListener);
...
```

If you need the current Position you just have to call `getCurrentPosition`

```
mListener.getCurrentPosition();
```

f.e.:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v2) {

        WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                   .getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            myWallpaperManager.setResource(icons[mListener.getCurrentPosition()]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: will you please edit you answer with my code. because i am not getting how to implement it

Comment: i've edited my answer. i hope it will help you now. :D